# Family of continuous maps generates the topology of X?

Tags: general-topology

I want to know if this is true: Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space and let $\{f_i:i\in I \}$ be a family of continuous maps $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that it separates points and closed sets. Then $\{f_i:i\in I \}$ generates the topology of $X$.

Any hint to prove it?

By the way, in case this is true, is the same also true if we replace $[0,1]$ with $Y$, where $Y$ is homeomorphic with $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\{f_i:X\to X_i\mid i\in A \}$ be a family of continuous functions into topological spaces which separates points from closed sets. Note that $X$ need not be a Tychonoff space. (On the other hand $X$ being a completely regular space - Tychonoff without $T_1$ - implies that the family of continuous real-valued maps or the family of continuous maps into $I$ separates points from closed sets, so your conditions are somewhat redundant.)
You can show that the sets $f^{-1}_i(V)$ for $V$ open in $X_i$ form a basis for the topology on $X$. To show this, take a point $x$ in $X$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$. Call its complement $A$. Since the family separates points from closed sets, there is a function $f_j$ such that $f_j(x)\notin\overline{f_j(A)}$. The complement of $\overline{f_j(A)}$ is an open set. What can you say about its preimage?

Comment: We define $V = X_j \setminus \overline{f_j(A)}$ and $B = f_j^{-1}(V)$.

Since $f_j(x)\in V$, we have that $x\in B$. Now, we take $z\in{B}$, therefore $f_j(z)\in{X_j \setminus \overline{f_j(A)}}$. If $z\in{A}$, then $f_j(z)\in{f_j(A)}$. We conclude that $z\in{U}$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @user73564: Could you upvote my answer then ;-)